# Uploading a file with CKEditor's upload functionality but out of the context of the editor itself

Tags: file-upload, ckeditor

I'm currently using the CKEditor and have it working with image upload and browse functionality.  In another area of my application, I want to let the user upload an image to the server, but there is no need for a text area at this point.  Is it possible to create a simple link or button that launches the upload functionality from CKEditor without actually plopping the textarea/html editor in the space I want my button?

i.e this would be perfect (with javascript too, of course)

```
<a href="#" class="btn upload-button"><i class="icon-picture"></i> Upload</a>
```

Comment: CKEditor only operates within its bounds, however you could do something very hacky with JS that would grab the upload dialog from a hidden CKEditor and put it wherever you want in the screen.

Comment: Do you have an example of this?